# Unpacking tar.gz into root dir with Gradle

Tags: extract, gradle

My project contains a couple of tar.gz files that I need to extract to the root directory of the project.

I made this as a test:

```
task untar (type: Copy) {
    from tarTree(resources.gzip('model.tar.gz'))
    into getProjectDir() 
}
```

When I run it, it's throwing this exception: org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: java.io.IOException: The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file.

I'm using Gradle 1.1 in Windows 7.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please provide the Gradle version you are using.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot. I'll update the question.

Comment: When you run this task are you sure no other process has a handle on the file?

Comment: I'm not doing anything that would suggest that. For example, I just turned on my laptop, ran "cmd" and the gradle task, and the same exception happens.

Comment: I'd be looking for files/directories in the gz that collide with files in your project directory that are active.  Also, do you have something open among the files to be unpacked?  If memory serves, having one selected in Windows Explorer will even make this fail.  In general, this seems hazardous - I'd consider unzipping into a subdirectory, if you can.

Comment: The tar.gz file contains a single directory which I know is not present at the time. I don't have anything else running other than cmd just to be sure. I haven't had the time to boot into my linux machine to try it out, regardless I need it to work on windows machines.

Unfortunately I need to extract it into the root folder. I don't understand if the lock is for the root dir or the tgz file. Because I was able to use mkdir and that worked fine, which makes me think is the tgz file, but I don't know. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 16):

I was able to extract it using this:

```groovy
task test {
    doLast {
        copy {
            from tarTree(resources.gzip('model.tar.gz'))
            into getProjectDir()
        }
    }
}
```

My only guess is that either the dir or the tgz file or both are locked during the configuration phase and it's released during the execution phase.

If someone has a solution using the copy task and not the copy method I would appreciate it.

Comment: Here you go: `project.tasks.create 'unzipStuff', Sync, {
            Sync z->
                z.from someTask.outputs.files.collect{ project.tarTree(it) };
                z.into(project.projectDir);
        }`